# malloc and obtaining recently freed memory

Tags: c, memory, initialization, malloc

I am allocating the array and freeing it every callback of an audio thread. The main user thread (a web browser) is constantly allocating and deallocating memory based on user input.  I am sending the uninited float array to the audio card. (example in my page from my profile.) The idea is to hear program state changes.

When I call `malloc(sizeof(float)*256*13)` and smaller i get an array filled with a wide range of floats which have a seemingly random distribution.  It is not right to call it random - presumably this comes from whatever the memory block previously held.  This is the behavior I expected and want to exploit.  However when I do `malloc(sizeof(float)*256*14)` and larger, I get an array filled only with zeros.  I would like to know why this cliff exists and if theres something I can do to get around it.  I know it is undefined behavior per the standard, but I'm hoping someone that knows the implementation of malloc on some system might have an explanation.

Does this mean malloc is also memsetting the block to zero for larger sizes?  This would be surprising since it wouldn't be efficient.  Even if there are more chunks of memory zeroed out, I'd expect something to happen sometimes, since the arrays are constantly changing.
If possible I would like to be able to obtain chunks of memory that are reallocated over recently freed memory, so any alternatives would be welcomed.

I guess this is a strange question for some because my goal is to explore undefined behavior and use bad programming practices deliberately, but this is the application I am interested in making, so please bear with the usage of uninited arrays.  I know the behavior of such usage is undefined, so please bear with me and don't tell me not to do it.  I'm developing on a mac 10.5.

Comment: For a better representation of program state as sound you might want to try casting the stack to an array of floating point numbers (as long as the array isn't longer than the stack is deep).  You could use a variable argument function interface or take the address of a local variable or function argument to get an address near the top of the stack in C.  This is an odd thing that you are doing, though.

Comment: Look around for some options to control the memory manager behavior. These might be controlled by special C library functions. In GLibC in Linux there are environment variables.

Comment: This is undefined behavior and therefor your whole program might do things that you don't want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely, the larger allocations result in the heap manager directly requesting pages of virtual address space from the kernel.  Freeing will return that address space back to the kernel.  The kernel must zero all pages that are allocated for a process - this is to prevent data leaking from one process to another.

Smaller allocations are handled by the user-mode heap manager within the process by taking these larger page allocations from the kernel, carving them up into smaller blocks, and reusing blocks on subsequent allocations.  These do not need to be zero-initialized, since the memory contents always comes from your own process.

Comment: Great explanation.  Do you know if there is a way to request previously freed pages of virtual address space from the kernel from the same process?  If the kernel actually keeps track of that it seems that would be more efficient then zeroing the data.

Comment: I don't know, I doubt it.  I wouldn't be too worried about this - I don't know about Mac specifically but on Windows zero'ing free pages is done with background CPU cycles.  I doubt zeroing pages is a bottleneck in your program.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is UB and therefor makes your whole program UB.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll probably find is that previous requests could be filled using smaller blocks joined together. But when you request the bigger memory, then the existing free memory probably can't handle that much and flips some inbuilt switch for a request direct from the OS.